# Am trying to post data but I keep getting this error "code": 400, "message": "The request data is invalid." on Magento REST API

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to post some data then call profPostAction to check for token, but this **_create function** is never read at all and the error Request invalid keeps appearing,

```
protected function _create(array $data)
{
    $action = $this->getRequest()->getParam('action') . 'PostAction';
    if (method_exists($this, $action)) {
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        die(json_encode($this->$action($data)));
    }

    $this->_critical('Bad request.', Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

//Trying to get the token and data supplied to get customer ID

```
protected function profPostAction($data)
{
    $token = $data['token'];
    if (!$token) {
        $this->_critical('Token is required.', Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $_token = Mage::getModel('grouponapi/token')->load(mysql_escape_string($token), 'token');
    if (!$_token->getId()) {
        $this->_critical('Token is not valid!', Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    $customer_id = $_token->getCustomerId();
    $_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
    if (!$_customer->getId()) {
        $this->_critical('Customer not found!', Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the attributes for the entity you are trying to create in your api2.xml:

```
<attributes module="api2">
    <entity_id>ID</entity_id>
    <field1>Your Field 1</field1>
    <field2>Your Field 2</field2>
</attributes>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bit late but most of the time we get this type of error if we do not send header's in request in my case I was getting this error because I was not sending the header **Content-Type Application/json** and if you are testing you are api's on rest client then write your data(json) manually(raw) in form. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've used PUT(_update) method and pass empty body.
And in Magento I found that empty body for update request is invalid:

```
case self::ACTION_TYPE_ENTITY . self::OPERATION_UPDATE:
    $this->_errorIfMethodNotExist('_update');
    $requestData = $this->getRequest()->getBodyParams();
    if (empty($requestData)) {
        $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_REQUEST_DATA_INVALID);
    }
    $filteredData = $this->getFilter()->in($requestData);
    if (empty($filteredData)) {
        $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_REQUEST_DATA_INVALID);
    }
    $this->_update($filteredData);
    break;
```